# I can't get the answer to the query correctly MongoDB - Find method

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My JSON:

```
  { 
    "user_id" : "1000" ,
    "boxes" : [
        {
            "box_id" : "12345", 
            "box_name" : "Box 3", 
            "items" : [], 
            "visible" : false 
        },
        {
            "box_id" : "2000", 
            "box_name" : "Box 1", 
            "items" : [],
            "visible" : true 
        }, 
        {
            "box_id" : "3000", 
            "box_name" : "Box 2", 
            "items" : [], 
            "visible" : true 
        }
    ], 
    "user_name" : "Jimmy", 
}
```

I'm just trying to get which box belongs to `user_id:"1000"`, which one's `visible: true` and which one's `box_id: "3000"`.
My query is:

```
db.getCollection("users")
   .find({user_id:"1000", 
          $and: [{"boxes.box_id": "3000"},{"boxes.visible": true}]}, 
          {"boxes.$":1})
```

But I'm always getting box_id:12345 one. I couldn't find anything about it.
Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation for the positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/), you can't use the $ with multiple conditions.  You have to use `$elemMatch` instead to work around the limitation.

> **Array Field Limitations**
>
> MongoDB requires the following when dealing
>   with projection over arrays:
>
> - Only one positional $ operator may appear in the projection document.
> - Only one array field, the one being limited with the $ projection
>     operator, should appear in the query document. Additional array fields
>     in the query document may lead to undefined behavior.
> - The query
>     document should only contain a single condition on the array field
>     being projected. Multiple conditions may override each other
>     internally and lead to undefined behavior.
>
> Under these requirements, the following query is incorrect:
>
> ```
> db.collection.find( { <array>: <value>, <someOtherArray>: <value2> },
>                     { "<array>.$": 1 } )
> ```
>
> To specify criteria on multiple fields of documents inside that array,
>   use the $elemMatch query operator. The following query returns the
>   first document inside a grades array that has a mean of greater than
>   70 and a grade of greater than 90.
>
> ```
> db.students.find( { grades: { $elemMatch: {
>                                             mean: { $gt: 70 },
>                                             grade: { $gt:90 }
>                                           } } },
>                   { "grades.$": 1 } )
> ```
>
> You must use the $elemMatch operator if you need separate conditions
>   for selecting documents and for choosing fields within those
>   documents.

So I would try a query like:

`db.users.find({ user_id:"1000", boxes: { $elemMatch: { "box_id": "3000", "visible": true } } }, {"boxes.$":1});`